# Dropdown list not working inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm having trouble with a dropdown-list, I want the chosen list element to be active when the dropdown rolls up. Currently the dropwdown works this way when it's placed in the main container, but when the dropdown is placed in a div (called aBox2), the js is'nt working!

This is my javascript that should make the dropdown work:

```
$(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){
    var selText = $(this).html();
    $(this).parents('.btn-group').find('.dropdown-toggle').html(selText+' <span class="caret"></span>');
});
```

I put my code in this fiddle, sorry that the scripts aren't working properly, (they work in my usual editor) but at least you'll see what my code looks like.

Thanks in advance!

JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/level27/eL9dd/

Comment: its working updated your fiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/eL9dd/2/ and included jquery 1.11.0

Comment: you haven't selected jquery framework in jsfiddle.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that! The dropdown problem in the div aBox2 still remains though, and the buttons 1,2,3,4 still don't seem to work in the fiddle. (A popover should appear when clicking on them)

Answer (score 1):

You have two unrelated bugs in your jsFiddle.

Here's the fiddle updated: http://jsfiddle.net/eL9dd/4/
Now the dropdown works.

I just commented out:

```
//  $("[bootstrap-switch]").bootstrapSwitch();
```

and moved bootstrap.min.js to the end of external resources so that it loads after jQuery.

For some reason you had style:

```
#aBox2 {
  display: none;
```

that hides this div and the dropdown inside it.

After removing `display: none;` dropdown in #aBox2 opens correctly when you press button with little triangle pointing down but not when you press button labelled "Action".

Please read here about how to construct dropdown trigger button correctly:
http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#buttonDropdowns

Basically you need to have just one button in your `.btn-group` together with dropdown `<ul>`. If you have more only last one seems to work.

Here's final example with `#aBox2` showing up and Action button merged with little triangle button and active.

http://jsfiddle.net/eL9dd/5/

Comment: Perfect, thank you!:) Now the fiddle works as I wanted to. Though the dropdown in aBox2 is still not working, the selected element is still not activated.

Comment: Does somebody know what the problem is? 
Thanks!